# Firefox window.open not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, href

This could be a little unconventional but I am trying to implement something where when a user clicks, a specific page should be opened in the same tab and at the same time another page should be opened and closed instantly without the user noticing

I'm using this code and works fine in Chrome, but not in FF or Safari -

```
<a href='https://www.abc123.com' onclick=window.open("https://www.xyz123.com","_blank").close();'>abc123</a>
```

Is there a way to make this work in FF and safari?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to open and close a page instantly because you want some server-side code to run, but don't want to display anything?  I would think that AJAX would probably be the best choice.  Another choice would be to create an invisible IFrame and load the page inside of that.

Comment: Daniel - you are right, the xyz123 page itself takes care of the server side action and that is why I am trying to open it as a web page instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a `'`:

```html
<a href='https://www.abc123.com' onclick='window.open("https://www.xyz123.com","_blank").close()'>abc123</a>
```

Chrome is sometimes wiser when it comes to fixing mistyped code. This is why it works on Chrome but not in FF/Safari.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what exactly you are trying to achieve but it will be better to make an ajax request to second page (xyz1234.com) and when you receive response to redirect to desired page(abc121.com).

Edit based on first comment:

You need to log use action. There are 2 methods:

1. As pointed before you could use ajax request to log user action. When you receive response (ajax.onreadystatechange callback) when logging have already been done and you can redirect user to desired page. Using ajax for such thing is not so common practice.
2. Do like google/twitter/facebook and so on. First log data then redirect to desired page. This mean you could write your link . When logging is done you can redirect to right page based on "realurl" param. Just take care about how you will send realurl param - plain text, encoded version or escaped version. Actually you must not send it as plain text, because there are some problems (there are reserved symbols in get methods), but both other ways will work.

Good luck :)

Comment: Hi Kamen Stoykov- I am basically trying to open a landing page (abc123) but before that i need to open a page that logs out the user(xyz123).